# Change picture when audio is playing (jQuery, HTML5)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, audio

I need some help with this:

```
<script>
    $(window).load(function(){  
        function swapImages(){
            var $active = $('#myGallery .active');
            var $next = ($('#myGallery .active').next().length > 0) ? $('#myGallery .active').next() : $('#myGallery img:first');
            $active.fadeOut(function(){
                $active.removeClass('active');
                $next.fadeIn().addClass('active');
            });
        }

        $('#audio').click(function() {
            alert("YESSSSSSSSSSSS!");
            setInterval("swapImages()", 5000);
        });
    });
 </script>
```

The "click function" doesn't work. I have to mention, that the audio part will be loaded with a PHP file after a previous jquery call for another action. So, what can I do?

Thanks!

```
<audio controls='controls' id='audio'> 
   <source src=". $final_file ." type='audio/mp3'/> 
</audio>
```

Comment: `<audio controls='controls' id='audio'>
<source src=". $final_file ." type='audio/mp3'/>
</audio>`

Comment: Correct syntax: setInterval(swapImages, 5000); Is it working now?

Comment: @nevermind: that shouldn't be a problem

Answer (score 0):

If the audio file is loaded at a later stage then the do it using .on() and not .click()

```
$('body').on('click', '#audio', function() {
  alert("YESSSSSSSSSSSS!");
  setInterval("swapImages()", 5000);
});
```

Comment: you don't see the alert either ?

Comment: nope.. but i think i will create a button or something to call. because it works with other div id's

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to change background while the song is being played, you can try the below code...

```
<script>
$(window).load(function(){  
    function swapImages(){
        var $active = $('#myGallery .active');
        var $next = ($('#myGallery .active').next().length > 0) ? $('#myGallery .active').next() : $('#myGallery img:first');
        $active.fadeOut(function(){
            $active.removeClass('active');
            $next.fadeIn().addClass('active');
        });
    }

    var aud= document.getElementById('audio');
    aud.addEventListener('play', onStart);
    aud.addEventListener('pause', onEnded); 
    aud.addEventListener('ended', onEnded);
    function onEnded(){
        clearInterval(window.audInterval);
    }
    function onStart(){
        alert('Started playing...');
        window.audInterval = setInterval(swapImages, 5000);
    }
});
</script>
```

p.s: try and use as little JQuery as needed. Just my two cents.

Comment: this works: `$(document.getElementsByTagName("audio")[0]).on("play", function(){`